# target="_blank" behavior in https

Tags: html, tomcat, https

I'm still really new to this web server thing.. But, I'm deploying a web site using tomcat. And, I've got a jsp page that has a link in it:
The html for the link is pretty simple:
. When I deploy the website locally, this works fine (it opens a new window with page == href). But, when I run the website using https, instead of creating a new window with the url, it creates a new window and adds "www.website.com" on to the url for the page that contained the link.

I'm wondering:

1. Is this a behavior of tomcat's SSL encryption, or is it something else?
2. How would I get the desired behavior (the link opens up a new window with 
   url == "www.website.com"?

Comment: You are using `http://` right?

Comment: if you're referring to when I run I run it locally. Yes, I was using http:// in order to test it. The site needs to be run in https:// though in the final version (which apparently is behaving differently).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `http://` to the front of the `href` attribute in your link to the external website.

So, instead of `<a href="www.website.com">Link text</a>`, you need `<a href="http://www.website.com">Link text</a>`.

The reason for this is that links without the protocol in front of them are treated as relative links, meaning the `href` property in your `<a>` tag will just be appended to the base URL of your site. See http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_link_href.asp.